# How to set custom User-Agent in WSO2 4.9.0

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to call soap web service from WSO2esb 4.9.0. This web service needs the transport header User-Agent to be as Axis2.but its default set as

> User-Agent: Synapse-PT-HttpComponents-NIO

but what i need is set User-Agent as

> User-Agent: Axis2.

Because otherwise they not response me properly, please help me  if there any way to set custom User-Agent.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried to figure it out yourself?

Answer (score 0):

change default User-Agent type and  need to change esb configuration below file `http.user.agent.preserve=true` in passthru-http.properties file  and then can pass any User-Agent type what we want using Header Mediator.